# Handling UAC Administrative Token

Tags: uac, freepascal, lazarus

to all, I am stuck at a location and wanted everyone's suggestion on this matter.

My application consists of 79 forms where numerous places requires admin privileges. Program runs on windows start-up, So cannot use default administrative token (asAdministator). Lazarus cannot create ActiveX dll's, so what other options are in my favor,  I am almost completed most part of my project in lazarus, so there is no way back.

Comment: You cannot bypass the UAC prompt, and this is by design. The usual approach is to add an application manifest to your application so that the UAC prompt appears only once, when you start the application. In this way your app will run as administrator and there won't be any more UAC prompts. (A separate question: What is your app doing that it requires admin privileges in the first place?)

Comment: my program runs on windows startup, and when adding manifest the program nevers starts.

Comment: Then I recommend not doing things in your application that require administrative privileges. You cannot bypass the UAC prompt, and this is by design.

Comment: you had taken me wrong, i am not going to bypass the uac prompt, I am looking for the logical ways to deal with UAC if i don't use ActiveX dll.

Comment: There won't be a UAC prompt if your code isn't doing anything to make it appear. I don't know your application, but it sounds like you will need to change the architecture of your solution. There's no other advice I can offer other than: Fix your app so it doesn't require administrative privileges. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application ***really*** does do some things that require administrator access

> and that is a really big if; almost nobody ever needs it

then the best technique is to launch an elevated copy of yourself, passing a command-line switch saying which action you want to take.

Lets say you want to *start a service*. You create a button with a UAC shield on it:

[image: ss]

Then in the click event you launch an elevated copy of yourself, passing the `/StartService` command line parameter:

```
procedure TForm1.StartService(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if IsUserAnAdmin then
   begin
      //no need to elevate, we're already an admin
      StartService();
      Exit;
   end;

   //We're a standard user, relaunch elevated to start the service
   RunAsAdmin(0, ParamStr(0), '/StartService');
end;
```

with a helper function to check if we have administrative privileges:

```
///This function tells us if we're running with administrative permissions.
function IsUserAdmin: Boolean;
var
    b: BOOL;
    AdministratorsGroup: PSID;
begin
    {
        This function returns true if you are currently running with admin privelages.
        In Vista and later, if you are non-elevated, this function will return false (you are not running with administrative privelages).
        If you *are* running elevated, then IsUserAdmin will return true, as you are running with admin privelages.

    }
    b := AllocateAndInitializeSid(
            SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY,
            2, //2 sub-authorities
            SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,    //sub-authority 0
            DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,        //sub-authority 1
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,               //sub-authorities 2-7 not passed
            AdministratorsGroup);
    if (b) then
    begin
        if not CheckTokenMembership(0, AdministratorsGroup, b) then
            b := False;
        FreeSid(AdministratorsGroup);
    end;

    Result := b;
end;
```

The trick to launching your app as an administrator is to use **ShellExecute** with the **runas** verb. i ever created a handy wrapper:

```
function RunAsAdmin(hWnd: HWND; filename: string; Parameters: string): Boolean;
{
    See Step 3: Redesign for UAC Compatibility (UAC)
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756922.aspx
}
var
    sei: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
    ZeroMemory(@sei, SizeOf(sei));
    sei.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
    sei.Wnd := hwnd;
    sei.fMask := SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT or SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
    sei.lpVerb := PChar('runas');
    sei.lpFile := PChar(Filename); // PAnsiChar;
    if parameters <> '' then
        sei.lpParameters := PChar(parameters); // PAnsiChar;
    sei.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL; //Integer;

    Result := ShellExecuteEx(@sei);
end;
```

Now you just need to watch for a `/StartService` command line switch on application startup. In this quick and dirty code i put it in FormActivate. In reality you would put it in your project file, before Application.Run:

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if FindCmdLineSwitch('startService', True) then
    begin
        //If we're not an admin, then use ShellExecute to launch ourselves as one
        if not IsUserAdmin then
        begin
            //Relaunch ourselves as an admin
            Toolkit.RunAsAdmin(0, ParamStr(0), '/StartService'); //don't forget to pass the command option
            Application.Terminate;
            Exit;
        end;

        //We are an admin; do the updates.
        StartOurService();
        MessageDlg('Service started!', mtInformation, [mbOk], 0);

        Application.Terminate;
        Exit;
    end;
end;
```

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.